# Apache PHP Files Downloading not Parsing/Executing

Tags: php, linux, apache, configuration-files

I'm aware that this has been answered in various forms previously but none of the suggestions have worked for me,

or some of them are out of date relating to configuration files that no longer exist

At present I'm simply trying to get the Browser to display a "Hello World" php file

```
<?php
Echo "Hello World;
?>
```

The Default "index.html- It Works!" Apache2 Page loads from:

```
/var/www/html/index.html
```

Set up 
Orcale Vitualbox (IP of 192.168.56.102)
Ubuntu 14.04
Apache 2.4.7
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6

```
System  Linux appliance 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:37:48 UTC 2015 i686
Build Date  Feb 13 2015 19:14:15
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini,   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20- pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini,  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-tidy.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
PHP API 20121113
PHP Extension   20121212
Zend Extension  220121212
Zend Extension Build    API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20121212,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
```

**In the Web Browser within the Virtual Host**

I can browse to http:/192.168.56.102 and it will display the above

but I cannot browse to http:/192.168.56.102/phpmyadmin

**Yet from my PC**

I can browse to http:/192.168.56.102/phpmyadmin

I already have libapache2-mod-php5 installed

In my config file (/etc/apache2.apache.conf) 
I've try adding:

```
Include /etc/phppmyadmin/apache.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mode-available/php5.conf 

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php    .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddHandler php5-script             .php
AddType text/html                  .php
```

The httpd.conf file seems to no longer exist as mentioned in previous posts

I've tried:
    sudo a2enmod php5

I already have a symlink from

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf to /etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

This is already enabled/uncommented

```
To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
```

I've Tried opening the file with the web browser from both 
/var/www/ 
/var/www/html 
Both files have 644 permissions

Php Short tag value is set to **ON** in
    /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

**I haven't tried:**

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

as when I include it and restart, Terminal says it cannot find it,
Suggesting it doesn't exist (or I don't know where it is)

Amending the .htaccess file, as I don't know where it is

Hopefully if you've read this far you can see I've tried various methods/suggestions and none have seem to work

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Is the web server actually running? Or did you do File->Open'?

Comment: Apache Server is running (via sudo service apache2 restart)

Comment: If you do a restart and PHP cannot be found perhaps you need to re-install?

Comment: What do you mean by cannot be found? Apache and PHP are running as indicated above in the main body of text

Comment: When I run "sudo service httpd start" = Httpd: unrecognised service

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds like things are not configured properly.